# PHP application connect with external firebird database

Tags: php, apache, firebird, lamp

I have an Ubuntu server (LAMP)

Now I want to connect with an external firebird database. How can I do that? 
Can I install a firebird driver? How can I install a firebird driver?

Do I have to modify my php.ini file?

Comment: please follow this link: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php

Comment: I don't understand where I have to execute that command:./configure --with-pdo-firebird

Comment: Do I have to install the full firebird first on my ubuntu server?

Answer (score 3):

I do not use PDO

```
#apt-get install php5-interbase
```

You do not need to install firebird on local machine
PHP sample code

```
    $dbh = ibase_pconnect("remote_server_ip:db_file", "user_name", "user_password") or die('die message');
    $q = ibase_query($dbh, "select * from some_table");
    while ($r = ibase_fetch_object($q)) {
        $some_value = $r->SOME_FIELD;
        echo $some_value;
    }
```